# Do you have to publish DefaultConnection containing the membership tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, server

Attempting to publish a website to my host which contains my custom database and the default like so:

```
<add name="PortfolioContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Portfolio;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

When publishing the site I can't login which I assume is down to because the DefaultConnection db isn't being created (containing the membership user tables), I might be wrong? I can generate the script for my custom database in Management studio but DefaultConnection doesn't even appear to allow me to manually create tables associated.

My error log displays this

> 2016-02-02 12:28:35 W3SVC30 217.194.213.135 GET /Login
>   ReturnUrl=%2Fdashboard 80 - 95.147.124.217
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/48.0.2564.97+Safari/537.36
>   - 500 0 0 1198 416 203

Though I'm not sure what that means. Sorry this is my first attempt at publishing a site. Thanks

Edit:

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\HostingSpaces\hannahha\hannahhamlin.co.uk\wwwroot\Assets\Common\images'.

This is the error it displays. This leads to me a problem I knew i was going to have to confront anyway. How do I include necessary directories for publishing?

Comment: My guess is that the login process is not set up properly, typically the get request gets redirected to the login portion of the web site, which after the login process occurs the user is then redirected automatically to the original page.  Read up on MVC login process.

Comment: It works perfectly when running it locally @John

Comment: Try this, run a trace of the initial get request locally then do the same where it's hosted post back what you don't see in the hosted environment.

Comment: only difference is that i get status code of 500 on the redirect.@John

Comment: 500 indicates something on server side is not working out well. It could be security, can find classes to load, can find proper redirect logic  etc.  Your next step is to look at what is going on when Global ASAX gets request, you can put trace points there to see exactly what's going wrong..  Including catching any errors and dumping the to a readable log.

Answer (score 0):

First, that's not an error log. That's IIS' default request log. All it tells you is that a client using a particular browser requested `/Login` via GET. In other words, nothing at all useful to this issue.

You need a *real* error, with a stacktrace. You can either turn off custom errors temporarily (`<customErrors mode="Off" />` in your Web.config), install something like [Elmah](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/logging-error-details-with-elmah-cs) to log errors for you, or use [remote debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx?TrackId=f32f8ed0d0b649cc81369cb2e2a8c6e0).

However, most likely, the connection string only works locally, and the error you would see is just a DB connection error. It's rare that the connection string you'd be using in development would match exactly with what would be required for production, so you should utilize [config transforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx) to change it when publishing.

That's assuming of course you even have a database server set up in production to connect to. Visual Studio employs a lot of database magic to allow you to focus on your code rather than menial implementation details like connecting to a database. However, when you go live, the training wheels are off, and you're responsible for making sure everything necessary is wired up. If you don't have a database server, install one. If you don't have a database, create one. Then, just alter your connection string to connect to that.

**UPDATE**

The error message is so far removed from this question was originally about, I think you would be best served by creating a new question and deleting this one.

That said, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve exactly, but anything under your project directory will be published along with your site (except certain special directories like `App_Data`). If the files you're referencing are in some directory outside of your project directory, they will *not* be included, and there's really not a way to include them. You *can*, however, create a build action that copies the files somewhere under your project, and by virtue of that, they should then be published.

Comment: In web.release.config i am instead using the servers data source
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="PortfolioContext"
        connectionString="Data Source=address;Initial Catalog=Portfolio;User Id=username;Password=password;Integrated Security=True"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>

Comment: Then, you definitely need a stacktrace to properly diagnose what's going on. Use one of the methods I described in my answer to see the actual error, and then edit your question to include the exception and stacktrace, if you still need help.

Comment: have included error in my original post @ChrisPratt